# Append not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't see the form, after I click test button?

```
<button onclick="gettest()">test</button>
<div id="uplaodForm"></div>

function gettest(){
    var page = "www.bing.com";

    $('#uplaodForm').append('<form action="'+ page +'" method="POST">');
    $('#uplaodForm form').append('<input type="submit" value="Submit">');
    $('#uplaodForm form').append('</form>');
}
```

Comment: not the bug but `uplaodForm` is spelled `uploadForm`

Comment: it is working for me however: http://jsfiddle.net/yhVZL/ what browser are you using?

Comment: it does *something*, however that's not the way that `.append()` really works.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a spelling mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this (cleaner approach)

```
function gettest()
{
    var page = 'www.bing.com',
        form = $('<form/>', { 'action':page, 'method':'POST' }),
        input = $('<input/>', { 'type':'submit', 'value':'Submit', 'name':'btnSub' });
    form.append(input);
    $('#uplaodForm').append(form);
}
```

Also, you should use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').on('click', function(){
        // code from gettest
    });
});
```

If you use an `ID` for the button then it's better. [An Example](http://jsfiddle.net/h9emB/).